# Component with nested router on main page

Tags: angular, angular-routing

My application is single page which has the component with inner routing. Application have the following structure:

```
    <app-header></app-header>
    <app-slider></app-slider>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet> (tabs component with inner routing)
    <app-footer></app-footer>
```

I want to make tabs component with inner router outlet. Tabs component looks like this:

```
    <div>
        Some menu staff with router links
    </div>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

App-routing Module:

```
    const routes: Routes = [
    {
     path: '',
     component: AppComponent,
     children: [
         {
          path: '',
          component: TabsComponent,
          children: [
              { path: 'nominees', component: NomineesComponent },
              { path: 'vote', component: VoteComponent },
              { path: 'winners', component: WinnersComponent }
          ],
       },
     ],
   },
 ];
```

In this case router doesn't work as expected, because in each router-outlet it loads the whole page and in browser I see main page follows after main page and only after that tabs are located. What should I change in my code to make it work?

Comment: You wouldn't normally add your app component to routing - it would be referenced by index.html and would house the root `<router-outlet>` that is populated by the router

Comment: Can you recreate your problem in a stackblitz?

Comment: you can make the tab component directly called from the app.component and then have only one router outlet with routes not in the child but directly to the path

Comment: Will the tabs component always be injected into app component at root? Or will the root contain other components?

Comment: @JohnPeters tabs component always injected into app component